# How to install openCV on windows to work with python

Tags: python, windows, opencv, installation

Im trying to install OpenCV to run with Visual Studio using python. Im using this link : [Installation OpenCV on windows](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d5/de5/tutorial_py_setup_in_windows.html) the problem is I cannot find file CV2.pyd.There is folder called CV2 with subfolders of some python versions. Installing using command

> pip install opencv-contribute-python

give me totally no result. How to install this im going out of my minds.

Comment: it's `pip install opencv-contrib-python`  (not contribute)

Comment: yes i wasnt copying that command.

Comment: voting to close as a **typo**

Answer (score 0):

Solved this. Found that opencv has problems with latest release of python.
Uninstalled everything and installed version 3.9 and its just working. It took me whole night fighting with this problem I hope it can help somebody.